# Regex - Including '+' when looking for a decimal

Tags: c#, regex

A bit of an odd question - I'm hoping to avoid some really ugly programming and thought that someone may have a nifty way of doing this...

I'm currently working on a regex that matches to numbers in a string, say "222".  Sometimes these numbers include decimals, "222.5" or sometimes in place of a '.5' it is replaced with a plus sign - ie. 222+.

Any thoughts on how I could write either a Regex, or a general C# line, that could interpret that '+' symbol after any number as a .5?  Here is an example of the current code I have (does not do anything with '+' symbols).

```
string match = Regex.Match(subject, @"\s*-?\d+").Value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string match = Regex.Match(subject, @"-?(\d+((\.\d+)|\+)?)|(\.\d+)").Value
    .Replace("+", ".5");
```

Comment: easy days - thats awesome. Thanks eh

Comment: @keynesiancross turned out there was a slight bug.

Comment: What was the bug? I went right in a threw it in my code... haha. Wouldn't having the double (\.\d+), with the 'or's (|) not have much difference.... I'm probably missing something though

Comment: @keynesiancross in the previous version, it wouldn't have matched ".5" correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, assuming that you are using the regex for searching, I would alter your regex to find the plus like this:

```
\s*-?\d+\+?
```

Note that the `\+` matches the plus symbol and the `?` makes it optional.

Now, I would wrap the parts into "captures" and extract the values.

```
\s*(-?\d+)(\+)?
```

The parenthesis allow you to extract the component parts of the match.

So, now you would have:

```
var match = Regex.Match(subject, @"\s*(-?\d+)(\+)?");
var value = decimal.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
value += match.Groups[2].Success ? 0.5M : 0.0M;
```

If you need to be able to match values like '0.5' or just '.5', you can change the `\d+` in the final product to something like this:

```
(?:\d*\.)?\d+
```

Comment: This has several bugs. -.5 is returning 5.0. You also have an unmatched parentheses on line 2.

Comment: @Yury: He never said that items could contain decimal points.

Comment: *Sometimes these numbers include decimals, "222.5"*